# Does encountering a zero pivot during Gaussian elimination imply that the matrix is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I was reading a problem about Gaussian elimination and pivots of a matrix, say $A$. The question is:

> During the Gaussian elimination process without pivoting a zero pivot has been encountered. Is the matrix singular? If yes, explain why. If no, write down an example.

I'm inclined to say: yes, the matrix would be singular, because we wouldn't be able to switch any rows of the original matrix $A$ to make it have no zero pivots, because we're not using pivoting...

Apart from that, in general, does having a zero pivot imply that the matrix is not invertible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing it is not singular.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

The first pivot is zero, but the matrix is not singular.

Comment: Note that in this case (as in all other examples where you have a zero pivot in reducing an invertible matrix) the remedy is a row exchange.